# Desktop icons and background not showing

Tags: xubuntu, desktop-environments, settings, 14.10

I'm using Xubuntu and recently changed my desktop background to an image. It was working normally, then the icons disappeared and the custom background no longer shows. In the display settings the box is checked for icons to show and the wallpaper is set. I had upgraded and rebooted several times, still no icons or background. It just shows the stock blue Xubuntu background. Anyone know what's going on?

Comment: Possible duplicate of: http://askubuntu.com/questions/451847/desktop-icons-not-showing-up-in-xubuntu-and-i-cant-right-click-on-the-desktop