# xubuntu 14.04 - when login icons and wallpaper dissapears [solved]

Tags: 14.04, xubuntu, icons, desktop-background

Xubuntu 14.04 - When user loggin in then sometimes his desktop settings such as icons and wallpaper doesn't display, and wallpaper becomes returned to default and also right mouse click shows not the normal desktop menu.

Comment: Possible duplicate: http://askubuntu.com/questions/451847/desktop-icons-not-showing-up-in-xubuntu-and-i-cant-right-click-on-the-desktop

Answer (score 0):

What's important is that in xubuntu the xfdesktop is responsible for displaying desktop, its icons and wallpaper so I tried many settings and finally came up with a solution.

I did login many times till the desktop was displayed properly with my icons and wallpaper, then I went to Settings and Saved Session:

**Settings > Session and Startup > Session - Save Session**

Now everything is back to normal, my icons and wallpaper displays each time I'm loggin in.