# xfce background disappears

Tags: xfce

I have installed xfce on Ubuntu 16.04. Sometimes, the background picture disappears and the picture that I had in Unity background shows up. Besides, the right clicking on desktop doesn't have all options that it has in normal situation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This could be caused by nautilus. I had the same problem, when I used nautilus, in xfce the same problem happened.Instead of using `nautilus` in terminal or in your key board settings, use `Thunar`, then your file manager starts.

Answer (score 0):

I fixed a similar problem to this by running `xfdesktop &` and then rebooting the computer.

You could also try this:

```
rm -R ~/.cache/sessions/* 
xfdesktop 
sudo reboot
```

or even a

```
xfdesktop -R
```

Liked this question (very similar!) but with more answers more scientific. [Desktop icons not showing up in xubuntu (and I cant right click on the desktop)](https://askubuntu.com/questions/451847/desktop-icons-not-showing-up-in-xubuntu-and-i-cant-right-click-on-the-desktop)

(also read on https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/151471/desktop-background-appears-black-when-using-xfce , https://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2229553 and https://www.reddit.com/r/ChrisTitusTech/comments/oqsx0k/solution_for_xfdesktop_problem_no_wallpaper/ )