# Xubuntu whisker menu became miniature and desktop shortcuts disappeared since presenting on a 800x600 projector

Tags: xubuntu, xfce-panel, projector

Not so long ago I gave a talk at a place where the projector needed 800x600 resolution. Sometimes I like to mirror my desktop so I don't get confused between my own laptop screen vs the projector. So I mirrored my display this time and started to scale down the resolution until the projector was OK, and that concluded to 800x600, at which point a lot of dialogs cannot fit into the screen these days, but that's another story.

My native resolution is 1920x1080, and at home my secondary monitor has the same resolution as well.

Since that talk the whisker menu shrank to a miniature size ([image: see screenshot of itsy-bitsy icon]) and somehow also all of my desktop shortcuts disappeared or maybe they are just somewhere really off-screen? How can I reset back anything to normal? Obviously I'm back at 1920x1080 resolution for a while now, and I'd like the menu and the desktop items back.

For reference the normal size whisker menu icon looks like that [image: white mouse head on a circular blue background like in the configuration]

---

When I right click on the desktop no context menu comes up. When I right click on the whisker menu this is what I see:
[image: whisker menu right click]

---

I have the `*.desktop` files in my `~/.local/share/applications` and besides those I should see some Xfce provided ones like thrash can and stuff. The desktop is solid color and I don't see the regular background photos. It's like Xfce persisted some magic value somewhere since that talk with the morbidly tiny 800x600 resolution, that messed things up and it stuck like that even tho the resolution is back.

---

[Desktop icons not showing up in xubuntu (and I cant right click on the desktop)](https://askubuntu.com/questions/451847/desktop-icons-not-showing-up-in-xubuntu-and-i-cant-right-click-on-the-desktop) solution cured my desktop icons and background

Comment: Did you try to remove whisker menu and then add it back to the panel? For the desktop icons: did you try right-clicking the desktop and selecting "Arrange Desktop Icons"?

Comment: @user3140225 I removed the whisker and added back but the icon is the same size. When I right click on the desktop nothing happens. That's strange. I also noticed that my background disappeared, which was one of the standard background images and on the secondary monitor it was the running mouse (without any extra configuration and people and I found it cute). Now all of my desktops are a solid background.

Comment: All of the desktop icons are in a directory and I see some `~/.local/share/applications` some of which I created a couple of years ago, so those files are there. Besides those I think I configured some standard items like trashcan and stuff, those come from the Xfce system and not from these `*.desktop` files. But I see none of those as of now visually. Xfce obviously persisted some magic value about that morbidly tiny 800x600 resolution, that f-ed things up and it stuck like that even tho the resolution is back. This is a suspicion.

Comment: If you right-click the whisker menu, then go to properties, can you change the icon to another one?

Comment: Also I think that this is related: https://askubuntu.com/questions/451847/desktop-icons-not-showing-up-in-xubuntu-and-i-cant-right-click-on-the-desktop

Comment: When I right click on the whisker icon this is all I see (I'm including in the question).

Comment: Then try right-clicking the panel > Panel > Panel Preferences > Items tab > select whisker menu and click the cog button. Btw, what is your Xubuntu version?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/97826/discussion-between-user3140225-and-csaba-toth).